# Wrap typescript interface value types with some generic type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Is there a way in Typescript to wrap all interface's values into some generic type to get another interface?

I have interface which represents an object with class constructors:

```
interface MyConstructors {
  foo: typeof Foo;
  bar: typeof Bar;
  // ... etc (many lines here)
}
```

Then I create instances of these classes:

```
const instances = {
  foo: new Foo(params),
  bar: new Bar(params)
};
```

Interface of that object should look like

```
interface MyInstances {
  foo: InstanceType<typeof Foo>;
  bar: InstanceType<typeof Bar>;
  // ... etc (many lines here)
}
```

As you can see it looks mostly the same as `MyConstructors`. So I'm looking for some way to avoid that duplication.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html):

```
type MyInstanceType = {
  [key in keyof MyConstructors]: InstanceType<MyConstructors[key]>
}

// Same as:
// type MyInstanceType = {
//    foo: Foo;
//    bar: Bar;
//}
```