# Typescript: How to wrap interface properties?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Suppose I have the following definitions:

```js
interface ISomeInterface {
  propertyA: string,
  propertyB: number,
  propertyC: boolean,
  propertyD: ISomeOtherInterface // bonus points for this one!
}

class MyGeneric<T> {}
class MyGenericContainer<T> {}
```

now I want to "wrap" all properties, so that I recieve something like that:

```js
interface ISomeWrappedInterface {
  propertyA: MyGeneric<string>,
  propertyB: MyGeneric<number>,
  propertyC: MyGeneric<boolean>,
  propertyD: MyGenericContainer<ISomeOtherInterface>
}
```

*Note: `PropertyD` is probably impossible, but in case the property type is not some "primitive", I simply want it to be wrapped by another class*

This is as far as I have gotten:

```
type FromInterface<I> = ({
  [T in keyof I]: MyGeneric<typeof T>;
                                   ^--------
});

type Wrapped = FromInterface<ISomeInterface>;
```

But this does not work, because `'T' only refers to a type, but is being used as a value here`.
I guess it's because `T` already *is* a type here, but obviously I want the "widened" type of the property that I am iterating.

Disclaimer: I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71023721/wrap-typescript-interface-value-types-with-some-generic-type) question, seems similar, but isn't.

Comment: Is [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/WP14zw) what you're looking for?  You have to define what you mean by "primitive".  If it works for you I will write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Yes, exactly. Thank you, the already provided answer does the same as far as I understand it. I simply meant built in types as `string`, `number` etc. Date is of course not part of them. I will edit the question to correct that.

Comment: What do you want to see happen with `{propertyE: string | ISomeOtherInterface}`?

Comment: Good question, didn't think about that. Probably I would want `MyGenericContainer<string | ISomeOtherInterface>`. But lucky for me that won't happen for my usecase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

- [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) to transform each proprerty in the input type
- [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) to select output property type depending on some condition

```ts
type FromInterface<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string | number | Date 
                  ? MyGeneric<T[K]> 
                  : MyGenericContainer<T[K]>;                            
};
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=19&ssc=3&pln=15&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGUD2BbCB5MAC2lXGniWQG8AoZe4AEwC5kBnMKUAcxoF8aNUJFiIUGHBFIiKKWvQAOUTAuhgAngEFWHLiG4AaOsiUq16gEKsQAV2wAjaEcXLVUDQGFWAETiRnJq7m3qwSuATEUNLkYsgA9HHI9pi2bCaYwmkwmFDIRMBpKRAAhPyCCAA2cGxpALLqAOIQINDACAA8ACoAfNQCldV1jc2tCB4pYHCg0F29VAI0GqrIAGLK2NGiSLPIALzUxgDaANLIoMgA1hDqmDDInQC6rJ0nD8gQAB6QIIxpujzIAA+yFsDmgQOQvkgyGM9Dh8IR9AA-Mh6k0WlwOi9jg9erDEQT6Kw0SNMeNwFMMV1Xt0ANyEhmMmF8WmCJYoTpQOAgNjZKC4Rh7VbrTaydphKRkLYQbpAA)